# How to get value out of bound textfield in tableview?

Tags: swift, class, binding, tableview, nsarraycontroller

It seems I cannot find a solution how to get value out of a textfield in tableview. Hope I can describe my problem accordingly.
Here are two pictures of my setup in IB:

[image: Picture1]  [image: Picture2]

I have subclassed NSTextField in order to draw a new background. This is working so far. But coming to the challenge to get the cells value as a variable, I can´t find a solution. The cell is getting it´s value out of a NSArrayController binding. I tried with `self.objectValue`, `self.stringValue` I´m always getting nil. Making an outlet is not possible as well.

Here´s the code of my subclass:

```
class ProgressView: NSTextField {

    func getOwnValue() {

        // Here I´m getting always nil
        let ownValue = self.objectValue
        let ownValue2 = self.stringValue

    }

}
```

What am I missing? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you simply able to retrieve the indexPath of the row you want and use your NSArrayController to get the data you are looking for?

Comment: No, can´t find a way to get the indexPath.

Comment: Where/when/why do you want to know the value?

Comment: I need the value for a draw function which is drawing a background color depending on the value in the textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:

```
override var stringValue: String {
        didSet {
           Swift.print(stringValue)
        }
}
```